# Haproxy redirect based on path

Tags: redirect, haproxy

Similar to [HAProxy reqrep remove URI on backend request](https://serverfault.com/questions/444965/haproxy-reqrep-remove-uri-on-backend-request).

The following concerns apply for us.

We have applications which were running with different context roots off one domain. However not all clients of the urls were changed.

I would like to redirect with a 301 redirect in haproxy if a request matches a legacy path.

Take for example `http://example.com/abc` and `http://example.com/def`

```
...
frontend https
  bind *:{{ proxy_port }} ssl crt /etc/haproxy/bundle_dh.pem ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4 no-sslv3
  http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
  http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]

  acl has_legacy_abc path_beg /abc
  acl has_legacy_def path_beg /def
  redirect location 301 https://abcdomain.com/{PATH_WITHOUT_ABC} if { has_legacy_abc }
  redirect location 301 https://defdomain.com/{PATH_WITHOUT_ABC} if { has_legacy_def }

  use backend abc_backend if { hdr(Host) -i abcdomain.com }
  use backend def_backend if { hdr(Host) -i defdomain.com }
...
```

The problem is how to retain the path in the redirect. I can do an absolute redirect.

Looked and `reqrep` but that seems to be for changing a request before passing to a backend. I want to tell all visitors they should go to the new domain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done using some temporary headers like this, inserted between your `acl` definitions, and `use_backend` keywords:

```
http-request set-header X-Location-Path %[capture.req.uri] if has_legacy_abc OR has_legacy_def

http-request replace-header X-Location-Path [^/]+/(.*) \1 if has_legacy_abc OR has_legacy_def

http-request redirect location https://abcdomain.com/%[hdr(X-Location-Path)] if has_legacy_abc
http-request redirect location https://defdomain.com/%[hdr(X-Location-Path)] if has_legacy_def
```

Depending on the actual configuration of your domains/paths and required redirections, it might even be possible to collapse it all down into a single set of directives, like this:

```
...
frontend https
  bind *:{{ proxy_port }} ssl crt /etc/haproxy/bundle_dh.pem ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4 no-sslv3
  http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
  http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]

  acl has_legacy path_beg /abc /def

  http-request set-header X-Location-Path %[capture.req.uri] if has_legacy
  http-request set-header X-Location-Host %[capture.req.uri] if has_legacy

  http-request replace-header X-Location-Host /([^/]*)/ \1 if has_legacy
  http-request replace-header X-Location-Path [^/]+/(.*) \1 if has_legacy

  http-request redirect location https://%[hdr(X-Location-Host)]domain.com/%[hdr(X-Location-Path)] if has_legacy_abc

  use backend abc_backend if { hdr(Host) -i abcdomain.com }
  use backend def_backend if { hdr(Host) -i defdomain.com }
...
```

Should the number of paths and domains be huge, you can use [maps](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#7.3.1-map) (where the key is the path, and the value is the destination host) to simplify things even more.

Comment: Thanks I understand this and its very clever. However to me it has a wrong feel to it, as Its obviously not a intended use case. I'm going to try to look at a different solution.

Answer (score 4):

I've got the same issue and found another solution that I think is better. This other solution works well with version 1.6+ of haproxy. It uses [http-request and regsub](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#4.2-http-request).

If I rewrite your example:

```
frontend https
  bind *:{{ proxy_port }} ssl crt /etc/haproxy/bundle_dh.pem ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4 no-sslv3
  acl has_legacy_abc path_beg /abc
  acl has_legacy_def path_beg /def
  http-request redirect code 301 location https://%[hdr(host)]%[url,regsub(^/abc,/newabc,)] if has_legacy_abc
```